# ZSH: how to escape the following command (variable assignment)?

Tags: zsh, variable

```
_test=`shasum -a 256 my "file here.txt" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
```

This works as expected. But the OCD in me wants to use something like

```
_test="${my-command-here}"
```

But because of the single quotes in the awk section, I'm getting a bad substitution error.

```
$ _test="${shasum -a 256 "my file here.txt" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'}"
zsh: bad substitution
$ _test=${shasum -a 256 \"my file here.txt\" | awk -F\' \' \'{print $1}\'}
zsh: bad substitution
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with `${...}` is called [Parameter Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). This will expand parameters - in your case, a parameter called `shasum -a 256 "my file here.txt" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`, but that's not a valid parameter name, as described in [Parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters):

> A name may be any sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores,
>   or the single characters ‘*’, ‘@’, ‘#’, ‘?’, ‘-’, ‘$’, or ‘!’

What you actually want is to run everything in `${...}` and for that you need [Command Substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution), which uses parentheses instead of curly braces:

```
↪ touch "my file here.txt"
↪ _test="$(shasum -a 256 "my file here.txt" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')"
↪ echo $_test
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```